# Can someone explain me why plyer filechooser doesn't work on my android device?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, filechooser, kivymd

I'm new in plyer and kivy. I would open a filechooser window when a button is clicked. The problems is: on click of button the window appear but first send None as selection.
Here my code:

`def select_path(self, path):
if path is not None:

```
        print("Ecco",path)
        pass
    else:
        print("Ok",path)


def file_manager_open(self):

    path = filechooser.open_file(title='ciao')

    path = str(path)
    print("Percorso:",path)
    self.select_path(path)`
```

And here my button code:

`MDIconButton: icon:"table-arrow-right" pos_hint:{"center_x":0.1,"center_y":0.9} on_release:app.file_manager_open()`

Answer (score 0):

path is a list, so probably path[0] will do the trick
ciao!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).